# Controlling multiple continuous rotation servomotor for a vending machine subsystem

Tags: brushless-dc-motor, servo

I am trying to implement/design my own snack's vending machine and I have already solved the  payment transactions through MDB components and communicating them by means of a MDB to Serial adapter to manage the info with an Arduino UNO R3 microcontroller.
Now, I am with the servomotors subsystem which will perform the rotation to dispense the products.
I will be using this commercial gear box vending machine servomotor (continuous rotation) Note: Column 1 and 2 from left to right is the translation of one another.

[image]

The schematic to control it provided by the supplier is shown below, according to what I read, to design a motors vending machine subsystem I need: Choosing a DC motor with gearbox for high torque, driver to control the motors, choosing microcontroller MCU. (Is this a driver to control the motor?):

[image]

The microcontroller I will be using is an Arduino UNO R3, so my second question is:
How could I control multiple motors such as the one shown above? I have read that it is possible to control many motors with I2C protocol or SPI, could somebody give me some directions or advice to go on the right path?

I looked a commercial vending machine and they connect each motor in a long PCB, would it be a kind of bus such as I2C to control every single motor?

Thank you

[image]

Comment: if you can read Chinese, would you help us by translating these images, imt_blake? If you can't read Chinese, why are you using components with documentation you can't read?

Comment: I have edited the question and I detailed that column 1 and 2 from left to right is the translation of one another.

Comment: Thanks, that's good to know. Then I'll just have to guess a bit: that switch "K1" might be some end-position switch, or something that closes every specified degrees of motion. You control the motor by turning on the high-side supply ("DC 12V/24V+"). So, you need an appropriate power supply, and *high-side switches* (typically, MOSFETs). And then you control these from your micrcocontroller.

Comment: That is right! I read that there are 2-pin and 3-pin servomotors, and the mentioned in my question is a 3-pin one, so I read in other questions a little about how to control them. I have the 12V/24V power supply from my 3d printer. Do you know or could you give me advice for how to control about 15 motors? (I think I should not use a digital pin for every motor, I read it is better to use another strategy such as I2C or SPI, do you know something related to it?)

Comment: I already gave you exactly that advice. You just control these high-side switches. If you have enough GPIO pins, why not use them? If you need to extend far away, or to very many motors, you can look into I²C IO extenders or shift registers that you feed e.g. via SPI, but you will need some way to check and count the  switch closings, right? so, in the end, you'll probably just get a cheap microcontroller for every group of motors, group size depending on the number of available GPIO on each microcontroller. You then centrally control all these microcontrollers, e.g. using UART, or I²C,or SPI.

Comment: Thank you so much for your directions Marcus! I will definitely read more abou high-side switches! thank you a lot!

Comment: @imt_blake what you have os not really a servo motor per se ... it is just a DC motor in a dispenser module ... the module also includes a feedback switch that opens, or closes, when the rotation of the wheel is in a position where the product has been dispensed ... connect pin 3 to V+ ... use low-side switch at pin 2 ... add a pulldown resistor to pin 1 ... pulling pin 2 to ground runs the motor ... pin 1 indicates the state of the dispenser module